# hive equivalent of group concatenation

Tags: hive, impala

what is the wrong with this hive query ..trying to do group concatenation

```
select ID,source_sys, group_concat(Quote||'_'||Quote_size::Integer||'@'||price::Numeric(30,4)
||'_'||quote2_size::Integer||'@'||quote2_price::Numeric(30,4),'|') as quotes from xyz_table
```

I am getting the following error

Analysis Exception: Syntax error on line 2:undefined: ...Quote||'_'||Quote_size::Integer||'@'||price ... ^Encountered::Expected: ADD,ALTER .....
Syntax error

Comment: Your query has no `group by` clause, so it is unclear how you want it to do string concatenation. Did you forget the `group by` clause, or you are just looking to concatenate values that belong to the same row?

Comment: apologies yes I forgot to mention it here the group by clause is there group by ID,source_sys

Answer (score 0):

in group_concat just use comma.. I believe only in oracle they use || for concatenation.

```
select group_concat(Quote,'_',Quote_size::Int,..) from yourtable
```

See more examples here https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_group_concat.html